# Is there a way to use object and classes from a web-pack bundled file in the other project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpacker

I am trying to use a "bundle.js" from one project to another node project.

A `client` package (`https://github.com/galaxyproject/galaxy/tree/dev/client`) generates a `dist` directory after bundling all the client-side component. inside `dist`, it generates several bundle files such as `analysis.bundle.js`, `admin.bundle.js` etc.

I want to use `analysis.bundle.js` in another node package. I just use prebuild client `/lib/dist/` as an entry point along with my project-specific /lib/index.js' and bundling project-specific `index.js` file and copying `/lib/dist/` file in 'web-pack' output without bundling them by using `CopyWebpackPlugin`. My web-pack file is as given below.

```
var path = require('path');
var version = require('./package.json').version;
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

// Custom webpack rules are generally the same for all webpack bundles, hence
// stored in a separate local variable.
var rules = [
    { test: /\.css$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']},
    { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$/i, use: ['file-loader','url-loader','svg-url-loader'] }
    
]

const resolve = {
    // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
    extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js",  ".js", ".css"],
    fallback: { 
        "path": require.resolve("path-browserify"),
        "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser"),
        "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
        "https": require.resolve("https-browserify"),
        "http": require.resolve("stream-http"),
        "vm": require.resolve("vm-browserify") ,
        "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
        "constants": require.resolve("constants-browserify"), 
        fs: false,
        child_process: false,
        worker_threads: false

  }
  }; 

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    var devtool = argv.mode === 'development' ? 'source-map' : false;
    return [
        {// Notebook extension
        //
        // This bundle only contains the part of the JavaScript that is run on
        // load of the notebook. This section generally only performs
        // some configuration for requirejs, and provides the legacy
        // "load_ipython_extension" function which is required for any notebook
        // extension.
        //
            entry: './lib/extension.js',
            output: {
                filename: 'extension.js',
                path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'tutorial', 'nbextension'),
                libraryTarget: 'amd',
                publicPath: '' // publicPath is set in extension.js
            },
            devtool,
            plugins: [
            new CopyWebpackPlugin({
                patterns: [

                    { from: "./lib/", to: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'tutorial', 'nbextension')},
                ]
        })
            ],
            resolve,
        },
        {// Bundle for the notebook containing the custom widget views and models
        //
        // This bundle contains the implementation for the custom widget views and
        // custom widget.
        // It must be an amd module
        //
            entry: './lib/index.js',
            output: {
                filename: 'index.js',
                path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'tutorial', 'nbextension'),
                libraryTarget: 'amd',
                publicPath: '',
            },
            devtool,
            plugins: [
                new CopyWebpackPlugin({
                    patterns: [
    
                        { from: "./lib/", to: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'tutorial', 'nbextension')},
                    ]
            })
                ],
            module: {
                rules: rules
            },
            externals: ['@jupyter-widgets/base','fsevents'],
            resolve,
        },
        {// Embeddable galaxylab bundle
        //
        // This bundle is generally almost identical to the notebook bundle
        // containing the custom widget views and models.
        //
        // The only difference is in the configuration of the webpack public path
        // for the static assets.
        //
        // It will be automatically distributed by unpkg to work with the static
        // widget embedder.
        //
        // The target bundle is always `dist/index.js`, which is the path required
        // by the custom widget embedder.
        //
            entry: './lib/embed.js',
            output: {
                filename: 'index.js',
                path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
                libraryTarget: 'amd',
                publicPath: ''
            },
            devtool,
            module: {
                rules: rules
            },
            plugins: [
                new CopyWebpackPlugin({
                    patterns: [
    
                        { from: "./lib/", to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')},
                    ]
            })
                ],
            externals: ['@jupyter-widgets/base','fsevents'],
            resolve,
        }
    ];
}
```

analysis bundle has some exposed variable as `bundleEntires` that should be accessible as described here

`https://github.com/galaxyproject/galaxy/blob/release_21.05/client/src/bundleEntries.js`

I want to use these bundleEntries in my other .js file as normal imports
from the bundled files.

When I tried to access the `bundleEntries` component such as classes and objects from the "analysis.bundle.js', as described below. I am not able to do it.

```
import * as bundleEntries from './analysis.bundled.js
```

bundled files from the client can be quickly reproduced with the conda env.

```
conda create -n TestEnv nodejs=14.15.1 yarn -y

cd client 

npm run build
```

Please suggest, How to solve this problem..

thanks